# Why does the `WITH` clause need to be reminded about the variable in Cypher?

Tags: variables, cypher, with-statement

Say in `group` property I have values `cat dog` and `chicken egg`. I want to assign to property `gid` the initial characters of the values in `group`, i.e. `cd` and `ce`. This is my query:

```sql
match (n) 
with split(n.group," ") as array 
set n.gid=left(array[0],1)+left(array[1],1) 
return n.name, n.gid;
```

I get this error:

```
Variable `n` not defined (line 2, column 48 (offset: 48))
"match (n) with split(n.group," ") as array set n.gid=left(array[0],1)+left(array[1],1) return n.name, n.gid;"
                                                ^
```

However, this works:

```sql
match (n) 
with n, split(n.group," ") as array 
set n.gid=left(array[0],1)+left(array[1],1) 
return n.name, n.gid;
```

I don't understand why is that? I check the [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) documentation but I don't see any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/)  docs itself

> It is important to note that WITH affects variables in scope. Any
> variables not included in the WITH clause are not carried over to the
> rest of the query.

In the first query,

```
match (n) 
with split(n.group," ") as array 
...
```

only `array` is carried forward to the rest of the query, `n` is forgotten., which is why you get the error.

Comment: I see. But assuming that it carries variables forward, what could go wrong?

Comment: Internally, the cypher execution engine saves memory on storing these variables. Some variables might have a lot of data associated with it. Also, I imagine it would save some processing time.